# Problems isolating xml from a string

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

In my python script, I am struggling with xml files. I am using urllib to download xml files and convert them to a string. Next, Id like to parse the xml-file.

[Sample link of a typical file](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1520006/000152000617000182/0001520006-17-000182.txt)

```
import urllib
data = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read() 
data = str(data)
data2 = data.replace('\n', '')
```

I wanted to strip data of \n, but data2 is not stripped of \n characters, sample output looks like this for data2:

`SwapInvolved>\n            </transactionCoding>\n            <transactionTimeliness>\n                <value></value>\n`

Why?

Also, since the file I pull is xml, I would like to go though ElementTree to parse it but I get an error.

```
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(data).getroot()
```

> OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long:

In the end, I want the xml from the link and parse it. I am doing it wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you need to escape the `'\n'` in `string.replace()` because your string contains literal sequences of `\` and `n`. Your code is looking for *linefeeds* but your data contains *string representations of linefeeds*.

Do this instead: `data2 = data.replace(r"\n","")`

Your second problem is that `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse()` is expecting a filename, not a string. Use `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! With this information I was able to fix it. Cheers there!